# Incorrect banner during maintenance

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange-2.0, maintenance

Either the banner for the maintenance page is hardcoded for the webapps site instead of varying by the site visited, or the photography site is misconfigured.  (The maintenance just now was too short for me to figure out which.)

[screenshot http://i25.tinypic.com/99p4z8.jpg](http://i25.tinypic.com/99p4z8.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same thing happened on the Gaming SE, last time I saw it (less than an hour ago) it still wasn't fixed, even though Jeff marked it as completed on our meta.

Comment: the fix was checked in by me, but someone didn't migrate the fix to haproxy.. guess who that was? :)

Comment: @Jeff: tell us?